# Automatic in c#

Tags: c#, arduino, arduino-uno

I've made an application in which I'm able to control the LED's on my Arduino. Also the LDR on my Arduino can communicate with the application, by sending a message, depending on the light intensity, to the form. Though it is only possible to show the message (which is an label in WinForms) if you press a button:

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            statusLabel.Text = currentInput;
        }
```

statusLabel is the label in which the message is shown. currentIntput is de message which is send by the Arduino. My question is if it is possible to make this code run automatically. So without a button and a status which is refreshing itself continuously?

Comment: [Checkout this tutorial on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tour-of-csharp/tutorials/branches-and-loops)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use timers to do this .
Timers in dotnet can run codes in the intervals you assign continously.
Write this codes on your button .

```
System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
aTimer.Interval = 5000;
aTimer.Enabled = true;
```

And then write your code in the OnTimedEvent handler like this :

```
private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, 
ElapsedEventArgs e)
 {
     statusLabel.Text = currentInput;
 }
```

Press your button, and every 5 seconds your code will run .

Comment: Was it helpful for you ?